# background image on text in css not working in mozilla

Tags: html, css

The following code is working on chrome perfectly but not in mozilla, kindly check and reply as soon as possible, thanx in advance.

**My html is:**

```
<div class="about-bg">        
   <div class="about-us-heading">About<br>The Apes</div>
</div>
```

**and my css:**

```
.about-bg {
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 90px;
    padding: 80px 20px 40px 0;
}
.about-us-heading {
    font-size: 92px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("http://creativeapes.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/building-back.jpg");
    background-position: -1px -82px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 95px;
}
```

here is my website link
http://creativeapes.net/#about-us

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-text-fill-color` is non-standard

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color

Comment: SVG maybe: https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/

But what I would do is create a PNG image

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use background-clip: text it's only available in WebKit based browser and it is not available in Firefox. Therefore you can use this polyfill - https://github.com/TimPietrusky/background-clip-text-polyfill

It works perfectly in Firefox and it replaces the specified dom element with a SVG. The only problem is that the SVG text cannot work with line breaks, so your content will be in one line.

```
var element = document.querySelector('.myelement'); 

/*
 * Call the polyfill
 *
 * patternID : the unique ID of the SVG pattern
 * patternURL : the URL to the background-image
 * class : the css-class applied to the SVG
 */
element.backgroundClipPolyfill({
  'patternID' : 'mypattern',
  'patternURL' : 'url/to/your/pattern',
  'class' : 'myelement'
});
```

Here is live example: http://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/cnvBk

Comment: @MuhammadUmerShaikh You are welcome, btw if it was helpfull then you could vote up and accept my answer :)